# Cakephp 3 belongsToMany won't bring any results

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following tables

Users
Companies

and i have a Many to Many table named users_companies

On the Users table i have:

```
    $this->belongsToMany('Companies', [
        'targetForeignKey' => 'company_id',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'joinTable' => 'users_companies',
    ]);
```

But doing

```
 $result = $this->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'Users.id' => 1,
            ),
 ))->contain(['Roles', 'Companies']);
```

It doesn't bring anything on the Companies Many to Many.

On the query.log i see this:

```
SELECT
    UsersCompanies. ID AS "Companies_CJoin__id",
    UsersCompanies.user_id AS "Companies_CJoin__user_id",
    UsersCompanies.company_id AS "Companies_CJoin__company_id",
    Companies. ID AS "Companies__id",
    Companies. NAME AS "Companies__name",
    Companies.user_id AS "Companies__user_id",
    Companies.created AS "Companies__created",
    Companies.modified AS "Companies__modified",
    Companies.reason_type AS "Companies__reason_type",
    Companies.fantasy_name AS "Companies__fantasy_name",
    Companies.document_type AS "Companies__document_type",
    Companies.document_id AS "Companies__document_id",
    Companies.avatar AS "Companies__avatar"
FROM
    companies Companies
INNER JOIN users_companies UsersCompanies ON Companies. ID = (UsersCompanies.company_id)
WHERE
    (
        UsersCompanies.user_id IN (1)
        AND Companies. ID = NULL
    )
```

I'm wondering what i'm doing wrong because on the Where clause, it adds Companies.id = NULL. Because of that , it won't bring the Companies.

Comment: I don't think anybody's going to be able to help you with that, unless you can provide some schema and data that reproduces it. I would also wonder why there's whitespace in front of some of the column names.

Answer (score 0):

I left some steps that could help you:

1. did you create these models manually?

   The [bake console](https://book.cakephp.org/bake/1/en/index.html) could help to reduce errors.
2. Join table should be named `companies_users` instead of
   `users_companies`. You can read the [Database Conventions](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/intro/conventions.html#database-conventions).

3. Check your `UsersCompaniesTable.php` (it should be
   `CompaniesUsersTable.php` if you accepted my suggestion on step 2).
   It should look like:

   ```
   $this->belongsTo('Users', [
       'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
       'joinType' => 'INNER',
   ]);
   $this->belongsTo('Companies', [
       'foreignKey' => 'company_id',
       'joinType' => 'INNER',
   ]);
   ```